# SQL query for grouping by (project, environment) and finding the newest entry for each combination?

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have a table with data that looks like the following

```
project  | environment | timestamp
----------------------------------------
project1 | dev         | 1644515845
project1 | dev         | 1644513211
project1 | qa          | 1644515542
project2 | dev         | 1644513692
project2 | qa          | 1644514822
```

There are multiple projects and each project has multiple environments. There are multiple timestamps associated with each (project, environment) pair which correspond to the last time changes were made to the project.

Is there a query to group by (project, environment) and get the the entry with the newest timestamp for each combination of (project, environment)?

Something like

```
SELECT c.project, c.environment, c.timestamp
FROM c
GROUP BY c.project, c.environment, c.timestamp
ORDER BY c.timestamp
```

But it should only return one entry (the newest) for each (project, environment) tuple. My database is in a Cosmo DB if that makes a difference.

This is my expected output

```
project  | environment | timestamp
----------------------------------------
project1 | dev         | 1644515845
project1 | qa          | 1644515542
project2 | dev         | 1644513692
project2 | qa          | 1644514822
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove the timestamp from the group and selcet the MAX of thetomestamo

```
SELECT `project`, `environment`, MAX(`timestamp`)
FROM 
c
GROUP BY `project`, `environment`
```

here os a mysql sample to show that it works https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86353790b7f73f766df01997255bdeb3

Comment: Do you know how I can also select the `id` from the table without including it in the `GROUP BY` clause? Would I need to perform a join on a subquery?

Comment: For the exact id when it is obtainable by MAX or MIN, has to be joint by a subselect where you gather the id , or you have the support of window functions like myslq 8 has.