# How to join two subqueries in SQL?

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to do a very simple join using two subqueries on a single table but I get the following error messsage

```
 Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":134,"end":139},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'INNER'."}]}
```

My SQL is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM c
) c1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM c
) c2
ON c1.id = c2.id
```

I've also tried

```
SELECT * FROM c c1 INNER JOIN c c2 ON c1.id=c2.id;
```

what am I doing wrong? I eventually want to change the subqueries, but I can't even get this trivial example working.

Edit:

Here is an example query which does not seem to work

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5821f6/1

As to exactly what I am trying to do, I am building upon my query
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71103946/sql-query-for-grouping-by-project-environment-and-finding-the-newest-entry-fo). I am trying to select from a GROUP BY, but I also want to include the id as well, without including it in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: By trying to be generic in the code you've shared, you removed the error in your query. As is, your query makes no sense but executes fine (assuming your table `c` contains a column `id`). You should share the exact query you're trying to run. If you can, share a reproducible example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Works fine here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ohLys6VxqKEmzdJVCEvj9k/0

Comment: That query is fine. What is your backend?

Comment: @CetinBasoz I am using Azure Cosmos DB

Comment: @TimothyPulliam Azure Cosmos DB is a NoSQL database. Why do you want to use SQL on it?

Comment: @TheImpaler because that's what it uses
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-group-by

Comment: @TimothyPulliam The proprietary SQL API that CosmosDB provdes may be promoted as "SQL" but it's a limited API, that would be comparable to a basic SQL only. You shouldn't expect to implement any complex query with it.

Comment: @TheImpaler yeah, I kind of figured that. What is the best way to query Cosmos DB, since apparently the SQL API is not working

Comment: nvm, I'm going to use pymongo to connect to the database. That should work better for what I'm trying to do

Comment: FYI Cosmos DB supports self-joins only, within the same document.

Comment: @TimothyPulliam - to use pymongo, you'll need a different instance of Cosmos DB, using the MongoDB API. You can't use pymongo to access an instance created with SQL API.